# Creating 8K HDR Stillframe AV1 videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like to create 8k/4k (DCI/UHD) videos out of mp3 audio tracks. The whole video would be a single image, but I'd like the image to be [UltraHDR](https://developer.android.com/media/platform/hdr-image-format) and the end output video to have HDR metadata.

I would like to understand the setting that would give me the fastest lossless encode of the single frame. Something similar to the `-r 0.01` hack for `x265` as mentioned in this related [Video SE question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/37243/creating-an-8k-4k-video-in-ffmpeg-from-single-image-frame-leads-to-video-longer).

Comment: Are you actually starting with an 8k UHDR image? If not… what's the point? You'd be increasing data size for no visible gain. This is the video equivalent of making flacs out of mop3s :\

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be something like this, scaling the image to 7680 x 4320 (UltraHDR), using a frame rate of 1 frame per second, and the libaom-av1 codec:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i input.png -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]scale=7680:4320:force_original_aspect_ratio:decrease,pad=7680:4320:0:0[v]" -map [v] -map 1:a -c:v libaom-av1 -c:a aac "output.mkv"
```